# php get level of url

Tags: php, drupal, themes

I am a complete PHP novice, and am just doing some themeing in Drupal. Just wondered if this was possible:

e.g.

`http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/conference-events`, gives:

```
<body id="conference-events" class="level1">
```

`http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/conference-events/rooms-capacities`, gives:

```
<body id="conference-events" class="rooms-capacities level2">
```

`http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/conference-events/rooms-capacities/bob`, gives:

```
<body id="conference-events" class="bob level3">
```

basically i have the code for the ID/first class, but is it possible to grab the level with php?

A.

Answer (score 4):

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// For this example's sake
$uri = 'http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/conference-events/rooms-capacities';

$path = trim(parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');

$level = count(explode('/', $path));

var_dump($level); // (int) 2
```

[See it on CodePad](http://codepad.org/jKxD7ChT).

Comment: Was getting to that, just was proofing it. +1 for using parse_url, too.

Comment: @alex: Also, don't you need to `-1` the count value, since you're ending up with a null entry due to `/` prefix of path?

Comment: @Brad Christie I think I already addressed that with `trim()` :)

Comment: @alex: Touché, didn't even catch that.

Comment: Note that the REQUEST_URI stuff is not necessary because this is inside a Drupal template, where things are slightly different, see my answer below.

Comment: @Berdir  See my comment below on your answer.  You will probably want to use $_REQUEST['q'], as that is what will come in from the .htaccess, or ?q=.  But, $_GET['q'] gets rewritten if you have path, so you will need to use $_REQUEST...which doesn't get changed.

Comment: This works perfect! Tweeked the output a little and added it to body_classes to output different levels / section I am in on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know exactly, if I understand you, but it seems you are looking for something like this

```
$pathSegments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$level = 'level' . count($segments);
```

Answer (score 1):

7 Responses and all seem to be missing the fact that this is inside Drupal. :)

And in Drupal, that URl will be converted to:

http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/?q=conference-events/rooms-capacities

with mod_rewrite.

Also, Drupal already removes the eventually existing trailing slash. So you just need:

```
<?php
$level = count(explode('/', $_GET['q'])); // request_path() in D7

var_dump($level); // (int) 2
?>
```

Comment: But be careful because the ?q= will get rewritten if you're using Path.  If you go to conference-events/rooms-capactities, path will change it back to node/123.  So, GET_['q'] will then return node/123, rather than conference-events/rooms-capacities.

Comment: That URL doesn't sound like an alias to me, more like a custom/contrib module. But you are right, aliases will be changed to the internal path. In that case, $_REQUEST['q'] should still contain the original alias.

Comment: Well, anything that isn't a view, or defined by a module, will be node/*.  So my best bet is that it's an alias with probably Pathauto in place.  But, not sure... I guess to stay safe, using $_REQUEST['q'] will be the safest bet, and work no matter the setup.

Answer (score 0):

The current URL is presented to PHP as $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - eg "/conference-events/rooms-capacities/bob".

You can use `$x = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` to get an array with an item per level. From there, you can `count($x)` the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Split by `/` and count the number of tokens obtained. Subtract 3 to account for the 3 / in the domain name.

So:

`$numLvl = count(preg_split("|/|", $url)) - 3;`

Comment: Any reason why `explode()` didn't suit?

Comment: @alex: not really. Works both ways.

Comment: Except one requires regex engine, and one doesn't :) See the note on the [manual page](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) too *If you don't need the power of regular expressions, you can choose faster (albeit simpler) alternatives like explode() or str_split().*

Comment: @alex: That's just premature optimization. You cannot REALLY see a difference between the two on a normal site (i.e. with say 1000 visitors per day) and just a few `preg_split` calls, which is most probably the case here. Running 50 trials of 5000 calls to each of the functions I got an average (+/- SD) running time of 0.0882 +/- 0.1732 ms for `explode` and 0.1319 +/- 0.2233 ms for `preg_split` (medians: 0.047 ms and 0.059 ms). So... as you can see, albeit faster, `explode` is not THAT faster (time regained by subtracting 3 instead of trimming and calling `parse_url`!).

Comment: Just sayin' for simple stuff like this, `explode()` seems to be best way to do it, if only for readability reasons as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have rewritten your urls, and can access each level as variable through $_GET or something...
`$levels = count($_GET);`

Just tweak it for your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to be missing the class that is derived from the last segment of the URL.
So, to get the count:

```
$level = count(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$page = trim(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/"), "/");
```